# Simple LINQ: Cannot implicitly convert 'short?' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I want to get a column (AssessmentID) from an input (AssessmentName_In_GetAssessmentNo). My code works if I "select a.id", but I want to get AssessmentID instead. I get the error when I change it to Assessment ID. Something to do with the primary key maybe? Both are smallint in SQL Server Management Studio 2005.

```
    public Int16 GetAssessmentNo(string AssessmentName_In_GetAssessmentNo)
    {
        Int16 Num = (from a in contxt.View_AssessmentCount
                       where a.AssessmentName == AssessmentName_In_GetAssessmentNo
                       select a.AssessmentID).FirstOrDefault();


        return Num;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AssessmentID` must be a nullable column. If you know it's not actually null, then you should be able to select `AssessmentID.Value`.  If it can be null, then you'll need to assign it to a nullable `short` (`short?`) and check if it has a value.  You can also use the null coalescing operator to return a default value in the case where the DB value is null.

```
public short GetAssessmentNo(string AssessmentName_In_GetAssessmentNo)
{
    short? num = (from a in contxt.View_AssessmentCount
                   where a.AssessmentName == AssessmentName_In_GetAssessmentNo
                   select a.AssessmentID).FirstOrDefault();


    return num ?? (short)-1;
}
```

Comment: should return type also be Nullable short?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi - note I'm giving an example of retrieving it as a short and using the null coalescing operator to return -1 if the DB value is null.

Comment: Why not: return num.HasValue ? num.Value : (short) 0;

Comment: @JBrooks - because the null coalescing operator is cleaner and has the same effect. Here I'm returning -1 as that's typically an illegal value for numeric id, 0 probably is too if it's autoincrementing, but -1 definitely is.

Comment: or... `num.GetValueOrDefault(0)`

Comment: The answer + the following comments just helped me understand better. Thank you all for clearing this all up!